# Linq-to-entities to normal linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have this line of linq

```cs
_cache = _repository.EntitiesNoTracking().Select(k => Crypto.DecryptString(k.KeyValue)).ToHashSet();
```

This of course doesn't work, as Linq-to-entities doens't know `Crypto.DecryptString`.
So the solution could be

```cs
_cache = _repository.EntitiesNoTracking().ToArray().Select(k => Crypto.DecryptString(k.KeyValue)).ToHashSet();
```

However, this seems to have a redundant `ToArray()` in there.
I supposed the next code would be more efficient:

```cs
var _cache = new HashSet<string>();
foreach(var item in _repository.EntitiesNoTracking()){
    _cache.Add(Crypto.DecryptString(item.KeyValue));
}
```

Isn't there some way of telling Linq-to-entities to convert to normal linq, without the extra step?

Comment: Use `ToEnumerable` if you like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need `EntitiesNoTracking()` because you have custom projection. Also retrieved data should be limited by additional `Select`.

```cs
_cache = _repository.
   .Select(k => k.KeyValue)
   .AsEnumerable()
   .Select(s => Crypto.DecryptString(s))
   .ToHashSet();
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought you should always use `EntitiesNoTracking()` on read-only queries, to keep EF from creating complex tracking overhead. [see the Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking) _"No tracking queries are useful when the results are used in a read-only scenario. They're quicker to execute because there's no need to set up the change tracking information."_

Comment: I know `AsNoTracking()`. Anyway what to track if you return just strings from database? Answer is simple - nothing. EF will track only FULL entities.

Comment: Ok, great. But is it /bad/ to add notracking? What's there to lose?

Comment: It is not bad, but it just do nothing and a little bit slowdown query translation.

Comment: "a little bit slowdown query translation" that seems to be the opposite of what MS says in the docs. Do you have some refernce for that?

Comment: I'm one of the creators of `linq2db` (alternative to EF) and I know that if you specify additional operator in query - it means additional logic to handle that. Query speed will be the same, but ExpressionTree translation should handle this operator, check internal structures, etc.